# skip exceptions in VS debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception

There is one C# file in my project that sometimes throws exceptions when I attach the debugger. I don't want to debug this file at all right now. Is it possible to configure VS2010 somehow to suppress any exceptions from this file?

Answer (score 0):

You could markup the class and method with [`DebuggerHidden`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a4d38ze.aspx), at least while developing.

It won't suppress exceptions, but will mean that the debugger will not debug into the file.

An alternative (not a great one, mind you), it to swallow all exceptions from this class - you can add a pre-processor directive around such `catch{}try{}` blocks so they only apply when passing a flag to the compiler.

```
#if SUPRESSEXCEPTIONS
   try
   {
#endif

//your code here

#if SUPRESSEXCEPTIONS
   }
   catch{}
#endif
```